# extjs: Loading screen icon not spinnig after some time

Tags: extjs

I have applied the loading icon in my application, It works fine on some places. But when there is huge data which is loading in grid that time loading icon appears ani spinning for some time after some duration the spinning stops and icon gets hang, but the record is fetching.

Grid refresh after some time.

How to fix the issue, so that the spinning continues till the data loads completely.

Comment: the [image](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/resources/images/default/grid/loading.gif) is an animated gif; i'm not sure you have much control over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not in ExtJS library. Problem is in browser.

When browser process `huge data` it requires a lot of system resources. So browser decreases priority given to GIF image animation render and raises priority for data process.

You can see such behaviour in [ExtJS DOCS](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/). Just try to open > 10 tabs inside docs. Traversing across the docs tabs displays LoadMask GIF image and it stops spinning sometimes. (tried in Mozilla Firefox).

Comment: is there any other way to avoid this issue?

Comment: I can't quite tell you. Is's the question for browsers developers or even realted to OS behaviour.